# Will a non-ECC memory work with motherboard and CPU that supports ECC?

Tags: processor, motherboard, memory, performance

I have this two components that support ECC memory:

- AMD RYZEN 3 1200
- AMD RYZEN MSI B450M PRO-M2

On the other hand I have this memory

- 4 GB DDR4 2400 KINGSTON VALUE CL17

## Questions

- Are they going to work together well?
- How ECC memory affects to performance? Is this going to work slower in this case?
- Will the opposite case work? A motherboard and CPU that do not support ECC memory with an ECC memory?

Comment: They'll work fine together. [Performance deltas between ECC and non-ECC are negligible](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/ECC-and-REG-ECC-Memory-Performance-560/), although non-ECC memory can be found with in higher performance variants partially thanks to ECC. Generally, ECC memory will not work in a system that does not support ECC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does work together.

Yes, this motherboard will run both ECC and non ECC ram (always in non ECC mode though) according to [AnandTech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13091/analyzing-b450-for-amd-ryzen-a-quick-look-at-all-the-motherboards/21).

> Will the opposite case work?

Depends. ECC unbuffered memory *should* work on non ECC memory, from [LinusTechTips](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/669767-using-ecc-in-a-non-ecc-board/).