# Asus X470 compatibility with ECC RAM

Tags: memory, compatibility

I currently cannot boot my PC due to an incompatible memory. 
I am looking for ECC ram compatible with these components:

- AMD RYZEN5 2600
- Asus X470-PLUS GAMING

I know the motherboard and the CPU can run ECC memory, but apparently I am not able to find a memory *really* compatible.

I have tried:

- Crucial CT8G4RFS4266 8Go (DDR4, 2666 MT/s, PC4-21300, SR x4, ECC, Registered)
- Kingston KVR21R15D8/8 RAM 8Go (2133MHz DDR4 ECC Reg CL15)

I am pretty sure it is the RAM causing problems, since with other DIMMs it boots seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your motherboard does support ECC memory, but probably not registered. If you absolutly want ECC memory, try to find ECC Unbuffered memory, like [Crucial CT16G4WFD824A](https://www.crucial.fr/fra/fr/poweredge-t130/CT8102846) for example.

FIY, another related question that was asked yesterday, [Will a non-ECC memory work with motherboard and CPU that supports ECC?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/will-a-non-ecc-memory-work-with-motherboard-and-cpu-that-supports-ecc)